# windows forms to run commands

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to launch a new cmd process, from that run a batch file to setup environments and from that run custom commands. Is this possible?

So far I have:

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.StartInfo.Filename = <setup.cmd path>
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.Start()
```

this successfully set up the environment but the cmd window immediately closes and i can't submit more commands.

Comment: Could you just run the batch file directly and pass arguments?

Answer (score 2):

Simply add the ProcessStartInfo.Arguments and pass "/K" as value

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "/K";
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.Start();
```

Passing the argument `/K` will force the command window to remain open
You can add also the name of your batch file after the `/K`

```
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "/K yourbatch.cmd args1 args2";
```